# EJB3Unit save-function doesn't really save my entity

Tags: java, unit-testing, ejb-3.0, testing

I am doing tests on an ejb3-project using [ejb3unit session bean test](http://ejb3unit.sourceforge.net/Session-Bean.html). The following test will fail with the last `assertNotSame()` check.

```
public void testSave() {
   Entity myEntity = new Entity();
   myEntity.setName("name1");
   myEntity = getBeanToTest().save(myEntity);
   assertNotSame("id should be set", 0l, myEntity.getId());
   // now the problem itself ...
   int count = getBeanToTest().findAll().size();
   assertNotSame("should find at least 1 entity", 0, count);
}
```

So, what is happening. The save(entity) method delivers my "persisted" object with an id set. But when I'll try to find the object using `findAll()` it won't deliver a single result. How can I get my `ServiceBean.save` method to work, so the persisted entity can be found?

**Edit**

My ServiceBean looks like this

```
 @Stateless
 @Local(IMyServiceBean.class)
 public class MyServiceBean implements IMyServiceBean {

   @PersistenceContext(unitName = "appDataBase")
   private EntityManager em;

   public Entity save(Entity entity) {
     em.merge(entity);
   }
   public List<Entity> findAll() {
     ... uses Query to find all Entities ..
   }
 }
```

and for ejb3unit the ejb3unit.properties:

```
ejb3unit_jndi.1.isSessionBean=false
ejb3unit_jndi.1.jndiName=project/MyServiceBean/local
ejb3unit_jndi.1.className=de.prj.MyServiceBean
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you don't have a running transaction, hence your entity isn't saved.

One option is to manually start the transaction by injecting a `@PersistenceContext` in the test, but better look for automatic transaction management in ejb3unit.

Comment: might there be a problem using: @PersistenceContext(unitName = "appDataBase")?

Comment: rather not. did you check whether you have a running transaction?

Answer (score 1):

Here we go..

```
public void testSave() {
  Entity myEntity = .. // create some valid Instance
  // ...
  EntityTransaction tx = this.getEntityManager().getTransaction();
  try {
    tx.begin();
    myEntity = getBeanToTest().save(myEntity);
    tx.commit();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    tx.rollback();
    fail("saving failed");
  }
  // ...
}
```

maybe this'll help some of you.